# Does using an implicate type caste change the type of the variable?

Tags: scala, type-conversion

I am getting an error from a piece of code. I will only show one line of code, at least the line I believe is causing it from the error report. It is:

```
b = temp(temp.length-1).toInt; //temp is an ArrayBuffer[String]
```

the error is:

```
For input string: "z"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:231)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:31)
at Driver$.stringParse$1(Driver.scala:59)
at Driver$.main(Driver.scala:86)
at Driver.main(Driver.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:78)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:24)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:78)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:33)
at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:40)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:56)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:80)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

From what I can tell, it is causing an issue with this. Since it is immutable, I know it cannot be changed. But I am not sure. I am basing this off of

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
```

Once I do something like my lone of code above, does it change the whole object? Temp is an ArrayBuffer[String]. So I am trying to access a string representation of a number, and convert it. But in doing so, does this change what it is and keep me from doing anything?

If you believe putting all my code will be helpful, let me know to edit it, but it is a lot and I don't want to annoy anybody. I appreciate anybody who can help me understand this!

*EDIT: MY CODE (Only here to help me figure out my error, but not necessary to look at. I just can't see where its giving me this error).

The point of my code is to parse either one of those strings at the top. It puts together and into one string and then reads the other two symbols to go with it. It parses str just fine, but it finds a problem when it reads "z" in str2, and "y" in str3. As one can see, the problem is with the second string after the and when recursing. Its also important to note that the string has to be in that form. So it can only be parsed like "(and x (and y z))", but not in any other way that makes it more convenient.

```
val str = "(and x y)";
val str2 = "(and x (and y z))"; //case with expression on th right side
val str3 = "(and (and x y) z)"; //case with expression ont he left side

var i = 0; //just counter used to loop through the finished parsed array to make a list
//var position = 0; //this is used for when passing it in the parser to start off at zero
var hold = new ArrayBuffer[String]();//finished array should be here

def stringParse ( exp: String, expreshHolder: ArrayBuffer[String] ): ArrayBuffer[String] = { //takes two arguments, string, arraybuffer
    var b = 0; //position of where in the expression String I am currently in
    var temp = expreshHolder; //holder of expressions without parens
    var arrayCounter = 0;
    if(temp.length == 0) 
        b = 0; 
        else {
            b = temp(temp.length-1).toInt;
            temp.remove(temp.length-1); 
            arrayCounter = temp.length;
        } //this sets the position of wherever the string was read last plus removes that check from the end of the ArrayBuffer
     //just counts to make sure an empty spot in the array is there to put in the strings

    if(exp(b) == '(') {
        b = b + 1;

        while(exp(b) == ' '){b = b + 1;} //point of this is to just skip any spaces between paren and start of expression type
        if(exp(b) == 'a') {
            //first create the 'and', 'or', 'not' expression types to figure out 
            temp += exp(b).toString;
            b = b+1; 
            temp(arrayCounter) = temp(arrayCounter) + exp(b).toString; //concatenates the second letter
            b = b+1; 
            temp(arrayCounter) = temp(arrayCounter) + exp(b).toString; //concatenates the last letter for the expression type
            //arrayCounter+=1;
            //this part now takes the symbols and puts them in an array
            b+=1;

            while(exp(b) == ' ') {b+=1;} //just skips any spaces until it reaches the FIRST symbol
            if(exp(b) == '(') { 
                temp += b.toString; 
                temp = stringParse(exp, temp); 
                b = temp(temp.length-1).toInt; 
                temp.remove(temp.length-1); 
                arrayCounter = temp.length-1 
                } else {
                    temp += exp(b).toString; 
                    arrayCounter+=1; b+=1; }

            while(exp(b) == ' ') {b+=1;} //just skips any spaces until it reaches the SECOND symbol
            if(exp(b) == '(') { 
                temp += b.toString;
                temp = stringParse(exp, temp); 
                b = temp(temp.length-1).toInt; 
                temp.remove(temp.length-1); 
                arrayCounter = temp.length-1 
                } else {
                    temp += exp(b).toString; 
                    arrayCounter+=1; 
                    b+=1; 

        } 
    temp;
    } else { var fail = new ArrayBuffer[String]; fail +="failed"; fail;}

}
hold = stringParse(str2, ho );
for(test <- hold) println(test);
```

Comment: get rid of all the semicolons at the ends of lines.  you don't need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does `temp` contain?  Your code assumes that it contains `String`s that can be converted to `Int`s, but it seems that you have a `String` `"z"` in there instead.  That would produce the error:

```
scala> "z".toInt
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "z"
...
```

Here's a recreation of what `temp` might look like:

```
val temp = ArrayBuffer("1", "2", "z")
temp(temp.length-1).toInt //java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "z"
```

So you need to figure out why some `String` `"z"` is getting into `temp`.

EDIT:

So you're adding "expressions" to `temp` (`temp += exp(b).toString`) and also adding indices (`temp += b.toString`).  Then you're assuming that `temp` only holds indices (`b = temp(temp.length-1).toInt`).  You need to decide what `temp` is for, and then use it exclusively for that purpose.

Comment: Hmm, I will take a look at it. If you want I can post up the code. I will recheck before doing so, but that should not be happening. It ran through a simplified version of what I am trying to do without a problem.

Comment: I posted my code, if you could please look at it if it isn't too much trouble. I have been looking at it for hours, but I don't understand why the error exists. I will say this. When it recurses, the error is there. But from what I wrote, it doesn't make sense how "z" could get into temp in that way. My logic should be working. It works with str.

Comment: I see what you are saying... It makes sense. But the error is not making sense. Its omitting somethings that should be wrong if its thought of as you mentioned. Sorry for dragging this one, but I want to understand why its doing that. In either case, I will have to change that part pass the int another way. Thank you. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

No, toInt doesn't change the object, it takes the object as an argument and returns an integer, leaving the object as is.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand you question because I can`t understand you code.
Let's try to simplify you code.

First of all: you have some expressions with expression type and list of operands:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

abstract sealed class Operand
case class IdentOperand(name: String) extends Operand { override def toString(): String = name }
case class IntOperand(i: Int) extends Operand  { override def toString(): String = i.toString() }
case class ExprOperand(expr: Expression) extends Operand { override def toString(): String = expr.toString() }
case class Expression(exprType: String, operands: Seq[Operand]) {
  override def toString(): String = operands.mkString("(" + exprType + " ", " ", ")")
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Operand
defined class IdentOperand
defined class IntOperand
defined class ExprOperand
defined class Expression

scala> Expression("and", Seq(IdentOperand("x"), IdentOperand("y")))
res0: Expression = (and x y)

scala> Expression("and", Seq(IdentOperand("x"), ExprOperand(Expression("and", Seq(IdentOperand("y"), IdentOperand("z"))))))
res1: Expression = (and x (and y z))

scala> Expression("and", Seq(ExprOperand(Expression("and", Seq(IdentOperand("x"), IdentOperand("y")))), IdentOperand("z")))
res2: Expression = (and (and x y) z)
```

Now we have to parse strings to expressions of this type:

```
scala> import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

scala> object ExspessionParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
     |   override def skipWhitespace = false;
     |
     |   def parseExpr(e: String) = parseAll(expr, e)
     |
     |   def expr: Parser[Expression] = "(" ~> exprType ~ operands <~ ")" ^^ { case exprType ~ operands => Expression(exprType, operands) }
     |   def operands: Parser[Seq[Operand]] = rep(" "~>operand)
     |   def exprType: Parser[String] = "and" | "not" | "or"
     |   def operand: Parser[Operand] = variable | exprOperand
     |   def exprOperand: Parser[ExprOperand] = expr ^^ (ExprOperand( _ ))
     |   def variable: Parser[IdentOperand] = ident ^^ (IdentOperand( _ ))
     | }
defined module ExspessionParser

scala> ExspessionParser.parseExpr("(and x y)")
res3: ExspessionParser.ParseResult[Expression] = [1.10] parsed: (and x y)

scala> ExspessionParser.parseExpr("(and x (and y z))")
res4: ExspessionParser.ParseResult[Expression] = [1.18] parsed: (and x (and y z))

scala> ExspessionParser.parseExpr("(and (and x y) z)")
res5: ExspessionParser.ParseResult[Expression] = [1.18] parsed: (and (and x y) z)
```

And now (as far as I understand your code) we have to replace string operands (`x`, `y`, `z`) with integer values. Let's add these 2 methods to `Expression` class:

```
  def replaceOperands(ints: Seq[Int]): Expression = replaceOperandsInner(ints)._2

  private def replaceOperandsInner(ints: Seq[Int]): (Seq[Int], Expression) = {
    var remainInts = ints
    val replacedOperands = operands.collect{
      case n: IdentOperand =>
        val replacement = remainInts.head
        remainInts = remainInts.tail
        IntOperand(replacement)
      case ExprOperand(e) =>
        val (remain, replaced) = e.replaceOperandsInner(remainInts)
        remainInts = remain
        ExprOperand(replaced)
    }

    (remainInts, Expression(exprType, replacedOperands))
  }
```

And now we can do this:

```
scala> ExspessionParser.parseExpr("(and (and x y) z)").get.replaceOperands(Seq(1, 2, 3))
res7: Expression = (and (and 1 2) 3)
```

And if you have integer values in string form, then you can just convert them first:

```
scala> Seq("1", "2", "3") map { _.toInt }
res8: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: I apologize for the vagueness. You code is much better because it makes it easier to parse. But I have to parse it in the form it is in.